# Anime series between 2000-2010 with monsters, military and crystals

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm trying to remember the name of a series that aired between 2000-2010 and had a style very much like "Children who chase lost voices". There were monsters in the series, people who became crystalized and the military using the crystalization to create weapons. What I most remember was the visual style, that was really similar to the movie that I mentioned. The series was in Japanese.

I remember that the climax of the series was the discovery that some large monster the military wanted to use was actually a kid.

Comment: Can you remember any of the plot elements or anything that happened in the series?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Can you give more discription of the characters,  the monsters or crystals in the anime? Main characters hair color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Fafner in the Azure*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/75/Soukyuu_no_Fafner__Dead_Aggressor) (2004), most probably.

The story is that of an island fighting against the Festum, yellow crystalline monsters. The Festum have an "assimilation" process, by which the target gets crystallized, shattered and incorporated to their hive mind (the Mir).

The Fafner (the big mecha humans use to fight Festum) weaponize Mir components, but the more they're used, the more the Mecha pilot risks getting crystallized themselves. For instance, this woman (S01E23, "Decoy"):

[image: woman pilot is covered in crystal]

As for the "monster being a kid", [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fafner_in_the_Azure) has this bit:

> Many of them are killed by the Festum in a process of assimilation. In desperation, they order **the deployment of a mecha called the Fafner Mark Elf**, but its pilot is killed en route to the hangar. **Left with no further options, they send a young boy** named Kazuki Makabe as the replacement pilot assisted by Sōshi Minashiro from within the Siegfried System.

---

I found it by memory, having previously identified that anime for [Anime in which people in mecha suits fight yellow monsters, but the more they fight, the more they turn into crystals and eventually die](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/206376/).